# I don't understand this function. [Codecademy Contact List excercise]

Tags: javascript, function

So the "for var x in friends" loop is going to search each key inside friends, which would be bill and steve, and then with "friends[x].firstName === name" we are checking if the first name is equal to "name", but how does the program know if "name" is Steve or Bill? I'm missing something here.

```
var friends = {
    bill: {
        firstName: "Bill",
        lastName: "Gates",
        number: " ",
        address: [' ', ' ', ' ',' ']
    },
    steve: {
        firstName: "Steve",
        lastName: "Jobs",
        number: " ",
        address: [' ', ' ', ' ',' ']
    }
};
var list = function(friends) {
    for (var x in friends) {
        console.log(x);
    }
};
var search = function(name) {
    for (var x in friends) {
        if(friends[x].firstName === name) {
            console.log(friends[x]);
            return friends[x];
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: It's an argument of the search function. You have to determine the value on your own, e.g. `search('Steve')`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here we have defined search as a function `search` which accepts an argument `name` .

```
var search = function(name)
```

and we use the function like

```
search('Bill')
```

So the function knows which name we are looking for, which is `Bill` . It will iterate through each item and compare each `firstName` with `Bill`. It returns the corresponding `friends[x]` , when it finds a match .

**The advantage of function with parameter is that, with the same function we can search for any name . ex : `search('Steve')` , `search('Bill')` .**

---

if you don't understand functions with parameters, revisit the codeacademy section [understanding parameters](http://www.codecademy.com/courses/functions-in-javascript-2-0/4/1) - js

Comment: Okay so I went back and did the excercises from your link on and I still feel like I'm missing some piece of the puzzle. Bare with me please.

Can you explain the part that we use the function as "search('Bill')"?

Comment: I see, so thinking about this the problem is that I never "used" the function in the excercise, that's why I was confused. Codecademy gave me the green continue button without me actually searching for bill or steve, just the code that I pasted here.
I think that's the confusion here.

Comment: @OfficerVimes using the function you defined might have been left for the next exercise something :) . but i hope you understood how it comes useful later .

Answer (score 1):

```
for (var x in friends)
```

This iteates over all keys in friends, resulting in two loop iterations with

```
x = "bill"
x = "steve"
```

Then with friends[x] in the loop you access friends.bill and freinds.steve.
The name variable is given as a parameter to search(name). This effectivly searches all entries in the dict friends for firstName == name.

Comment: Okay so the part that is not clear to me is the if statement inside the for loop. if(friends[x].firstName === name) When did I assign "bill" and "steve" to name so that the computer know it's a match? up until that point I understand everything I think.